# GIT moving to master detached my HEAD

Tags: git, github

A few days ago I messed up my app and branched from master to recover from my error. This morning I noticed I couldn't push to Github because I wasn't on master so I checked out master and received this warning:

> you are leaving 6 commits behind, not connected to any of your
>   branches

I did a git reflog and got

```
651c63a HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from 64c5d8d2abf3c6337ee8a9d6ea91b40c5b31d2e3 to master
64c5d8d HEAD@{1}: commit: preparing to move Ramp Receiving to TOP LEVEL
0f12bf1 HEAD@{2}: commit: receiving custom cell complete
3df40ec HEAD@{3}: commit: custom cell outlets and actions
09f0ef9 HEAD@{4}: commit: added button bar to Ramp Receiving
813df97 HEAD@{5}: commit: rounded buttons
91d4d47 HEAD@{6}: commit: recovered
2d7dbb9 HEAD@{7}: checkout: moving from master to 2d7dbb9f1d359bbb2393e0cf5c246f19f13ac818
```

Before I mess up AGAIN, how can I get master to the "preparing to move Ramp Receiving to TOP LEVEL" state so I can push to github and get back to work?

THANKS!!!

Comment: Can you post the commands you did?

Comment: I was trying to find out how to see the history since it started 3 days ago but no luck

Comment: Create a branch. This will stop the commits being unreachable.

Comment: I did git checkout 64c5d8d to get back to work and then git checkout -b master_recover, so I am now on a branch (yay) with all my work ... now it's git merge master and then I can push ... right?

Answer (score 2):

The feedback you are getting would be consistent with working in a detached HEAD state.  I don't know how you got there, nor does your question obviously state this.  But if correct, a quick fix to save your work would be to just checkout a new branch from where you are:

```
git checkout -b master_hotfix
```

Now you will be on a bona fide local Git branch `master_hotfix`, and your 6 commits should be part of that branch.  You may merge this fix branch into `master` or maybe push to the repo and issue a pull request back into `master`.

**Edit:**

As @Mark pointed out in his answer, the reflog shows that in fact you are already on `master`.  So if you want to create a new branch from your prior detached HEAD state, you may checkout that commit and then create the branch from there:

```
git checkout 64c5d8d
git checkout -b master_hotfix
```

Comment: if I checkout the branch from master, will it include the branches because the local xcode right now is a look at 3 days ago

Comment: My answer would be creating the branch from whatever point at which you entered the detached HEAD state, plus your six commits.  This is (IMO) the easiest way to go.  If this won't work, then you can always cherry pick the six commits directly onto master or some other branch.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I understand what you are suggesting but I don't know how to get BACK to where I was before I checked out master because that's where my new stuff is ... there's no branch I can see to checkout

Comment: You are missing the point of my answer.  You _aren't_ on a branch right now.  So you may checkout a branch from your current position, or cherry-pick the commits over to master.

Comment: but I am on master

Comment: I did "git checkout master" which gave me the warning that I was leaving 6 commits behind

Comment: I think this is my only hope ... 651c63a HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from 64c5d8d2abf3c6337ee8a9d6ea91b40c5b31d2e3 to master
64c5d8d HEAD@{3}: commit: preparing to move Ramp Receiving to TOP LEVEL

Answer (score 2):

First a little background about why git gave the warning, and then I'll come back to the question itself...

*Why the Warning*

Your reflog shows that when you went back to recover from your mistake, you did something like

```
git checkout 2d7dbb9f1
```

(Or you might have said `git checkout HEAD^`, or `git checkout HEAD~3`, or whatever other expression would navigate to the `2d7dbb9f1` commit.)

When you did this, you should have received a warning that you were going into "detached `HEAD`" state.  This is a condition where no branch is checked out, meaning as you make commits no branch is automatically moving to point to those new commits.  Only your current `HEAD` (and the reflog) is keeping those commits "reachable".

At any time when you're in detached head state, if you want to start making commits parented at the commit you have checked out, you can create a new branch

```
git checkout -b new_branch
```

By using `checkout -b` to create the branch, you also check it out, so it will move with you as you create new commits.  Now you're just on a branch, not in detached head state anymore.

Since you didn't do that, when you checked out `master` git warned you that you were leaving "dangling" or "unreachable" commits behind.  If you don't take steps to preserve them, they'll eventually be lost.  For now the reflog keeps them alive, but it will eventually expire.

*What to Do Now*

So how do you preserve the commits?  There are a few options.

You asked about moving `master` to `64c5d8d`.  The short answer is

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard 64c5d8d
```

The long answer is... are you sure that's what you want to do?  If `origin/master` is reachable from `64c5d8d`, and if you don't want any of the un-pushed commits *currently* on master (but not reachable from `64c5d8d`), then this is ok.  But be aware, this makes *those* commits "unreachable" in the course of recovering the newer ones.

If `origin/master` *isn't* reachable from `64c5d8d` - i.e. if when creating the branch you backed up past a commit that had been pushed, per the diagram below - this complicates matters.

```
                      C -- D <--(master)
                     /
x -- x -- x -- A -- B <--(origin/master)
                \
                 X -- Y -- Z=64c5d8d
```

In this example, you'd have found that `B`, `C`, and `D` were "bad", but by that time `B` had been pushed.  In that case, resetting `master` attempts to remove `B` from the branch history.  This creates an "upstream rebase"-like condition, which will cause trouble with others who've cloned `origin`.  See the `git rebase` documentation for information about how you'd have to coordinate and clean this up, if it applies.

In that situation, an alternative would be to revert `B` on master and then merge (or rebase-and-fast-forward) the new commits onto `master`, so that you don't remove anything from history.

Another option altogether - and the first thing I'd do while figuring out the goal state - is to create a new branch for the new commits.  The reflog shows the last of the new commits is at `HEAD@{1}`, so if that's still current you can `git checkout HEAD@{1}`.  Alternately

```
git checkout 64c5d8d
```

will work, since that's the abbreviated hash for the last dangling commit (also from the reflog).  Then

```
git checkout -b some_branch_name
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Not sure why you blame me for the votes on your answer, but if you're asking what's wrong with your answer I can tell you that.  (1) You say it's unclear how OP got into detached HEAD when the transition to detached HEAD is right there in the reflog output.  (2) Both in your answer and comments, you give advice that assumes OP is still on the new commits, when both OP's comments and the reflog show that OP in fact moved back to `master`

Comment: This answer is good detective work +1.  We both suggested creating a new branch from the detached state, so I will leave my answer up.